# MS Project and Android

Tags: android, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I'm trying to develop an app to retrieve information's about projects (basically the `.mpp` file) stored in a **Project Server (2013)**. We also have a `PWA` installed.

The problem is that I have no idea how I can do the requests to the server to retrieve those information's.

Does someone knows where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST interface exposed by Project Server might be a useful place to start: Reference documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj669820.aspx.